# site wide issue script function not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have been running into an error every time we try to run a script from Google Sheets.

> Script function testScript could not be found

This started with one sheet, but then users reported it with any sheet that has a script. Nothing has changed with the scripts, the site settings, people's accounts, permissions, etc. Everything is as it was last week, yet as of Monday, we can not get any script to run.

Unfortunately, I asked if I could share a document here, but was denied in order to protect company secrets and stuff.

I tried copying the Sheet to my account, freeing it from permissions, and I got the same results. I even have an old copy on my account I made when troubleshooting a different issue and it is affected as well.

I will admit, I am not sure how to proceed since I am humble Level 1 IT Support Man.

```
function testScript() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Data = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var Analysis = ss.getSheetByName("Analysis");
  var Parameters = ss.getSheetByName("Parameters");
  var Vapor = ss.getSheetByName("User Survey Form");
  var WDevice = ss.getSheetByName("WDevice Qualification and Data Entry Form");
  var Source = ss.getSheetByName("mdevice Qualification Form");

// Verify a testerID has been entered

  var testerIDvalue = Vapor.getRange(4, 7).getValue();
  Logger.log("testerIDvalue= "+testerIDvalue);

  if( testerIDvalue == "" ){
     Vapor.getRange(7,10).setValue("Error: Tester ID can not be blank");
     Logger.log("Exiting, testerID+ "+testerID);
     return;
  };

  Vapor.getRange(7,10).setValue("Working");

  var count = Parameters.getRange(19,4).getValue();
  var lastRow = count+2;
  Logger.log("Data to row: "+lastRow);

  //getRange(row, column)
  //copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)

  var date = Vapor.getRange(3, 3).getValue();
  Data.getRange(lastRow,2).setValue(date);  
  Logger.log(date);

  // User Survey Form Data

  var WDeviceID = Vapor.getRange(3, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 3, 3, lastRow, lastRow);
  var mdeviceID = Vapor.getRange(3, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 4, 4, lastRow, lastRow);
  var testerID = Vapor.getRange(4, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 5,5 , lastRow, lastRow);
  var acceptID = Vapor.getRange(5, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 6,6 , lastRow, lastRow);
  var mdeviceDate = Vapor.getRange(6, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 7, 7, lastRow, lastRow);
  var lPressureModel = Vapor.getRange(7, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 8, 8, lastRow, lastRow);
  var lPressureSerial = Vapor.getRange(8, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 9, 9, lastRow, lastRow);
  var lPressureProbeModel = Vapor.getRange(9, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 10, 10, lastRow, lastRow);
  var lPressureProbeSerial = Vapor.getRange(10, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 11, 11, lastRow, lastRow);
  var lPressureCalReqDate = Vapor.getRange(11, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 12, 12, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sPressureModel = Vapor.getRange(12, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 13, 13, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sPressureSerial = Vapor.getRange(13, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 14, 14, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sPressureCalReqDate = Vapor.getRange(14, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 15, 15, lastRow, lastRow);
  var ionSurveyModel = Vapor.getRange(15, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 16, 16, lastRow, lastRow);
  var ionSurveySerial = Vapor.getRange(16, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 17, 17, lastRow, lastRow);
  var ionSurveyCalReqDate = Vapor.getRange(17, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 18, 18, lastRow, lastRow);
  var mdeviceSpeed =  Vapor.getRange(18, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 19, 19, lastRow, lastRow);
  var mdeviceShielding = Vapor.getRange(19, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 20, 20, lastRow, lastRow);
  var peakEnergy = Vapor.getRange(20, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 21, 21, lastRow, lastRow);
  var effEnergy = Vapor.getRange(21, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 22, 22, lastRow, lastRow);
  var WDeviceShielding = Vapor.getRange(22, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 23, 23, lastRow, lastRow);
  var notes = Vapor.getRange(23, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 24, 24, lastRow, lastRow);
  var rtssoXRC = Vapor.getRange(25, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 25, 25, lastRow, lastRow);
  var shutterinterlockTest = Vapor.getRange(26, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 26, 26, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sourceCoverinterlocktest = Vapor.getRange(27, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 27, 27, lastRow, lastRow);
  var passwortest = Vapor.getRange(28, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 28, 28, lastRow, lastRow);
  var redLEDtest = Vapor.getRange(29, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 29, 29, lastRow, lastRow);
  var redLEDblinktest = Vapor.getRange(30, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 30, 30, lastRow, lastRow);
  var xonindicatortest = Vapor.getRange(31, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 31, 31, lastRow, lastRow);
  var airshottest = Vapor.getRange(32, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 32, 32, lastRow, lastRow);


 // User Survey Data

  var FWHS2 = WDevice.getRange(6, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 37, 37, lastRow, lastRow);
  var SetRatio1 = WDevice.getRange(7, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 38, 38, lastRow, lastRow);
  var slowCounts1 = WDevice.getRange(8, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 39, 39, lastRow, lastRow);
  var FWHM2 = WDevice.getRange(6, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 40, 40, lastRow, lastRow);
  var SetRatio2 = WDevice.getRange(7, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 41, 41, lastRow, lastRow);
  var slowCounts2 = WDevice.getRange(8, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 42, 42, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var FWHM3 = WDevice.getRange(6, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 43, 43, lastRow, lastRow);
  var SetRatio3 = WDevice.getRange(7, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 44, 44, lastRow, lastRow);
  var slowCounts3 = WDevice.getRange(8, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 45, 45, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var background = WDevice.getRange(10, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 46, 46, lastRow, lastRow);
  var leakage1 = WDevice.getRange(11, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 47, 47, lastRow, lastRow);
  var leakage2 = WDevice.getRange(12, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 48, 48, lastRow, lastRow);
  var leakage3 = WDevice.getRange(13, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 49, 49, lastRow, lastRow);
  var leakage4 = WDevice.getRange(14, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 50, 50, lastRow, lastRow);
  var leakage5 = WDevice.getRange(15, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 51, 51, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sourceDoseTime = WDevice.getRange(17, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 52, 52, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sourceDose = WDevice.getRange(17, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 53, 53, lastRow, lastRow);
  var calTime = WDevice.getRange(17, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 54, 54, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sourceLeakage = WDevice.getRange(19, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 55, 55, lastRow, lastRow);
  var calsperHour = WDevice.getRange(20, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 56, 56, lastRow, lastRow);

 // Update Calculations

// Format
  var dmaxcol = Data.getLastColumn();
  Data.getRange(lastRow-1, 1, 1, dmaxcol).copyFormatToRange(Data, 1, dmaxcol, lastRow, lastRow);
  Data.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(lastRow-1); 

// Calculated Data

//  var WDeviceRadSurveyPass = WDevice.getRange(21, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 57, 57, lastRow, lastRow);   (Translate Results to 1/0 format)
  var cell = Data.getRange( lastRow, 57, 1, 1);
  var WDeviceRadSurveyPass = WDevice.getRange(21, 3);
  var cell = Data.getRange(lastRow, 57, 1, 1);
  if( WDeviceRadSurveyPass.getValue() == "Pass") {
    cell.setValue(1);
    }
  else  {
    cell.setValue(0);
    };

          // not needed  var WDeviceLeakagePass = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 58, 58, lastRow, lastRow);  //No field
          // not needed  var WDeviceMaxBrightPass = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 59, 59, lastRow, lastRow);  //No field
          // not needed  var WDeviceMaxCountsPass = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 60, 60, lastRow, lastRow);  //No field
          // not needed  var SourceBrightPass = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 61, 61, lastRow, lastRow);  //No field


//  var S2RadSurveyPass = WDevice.getRange(21, 3).copyValuesToRange(Data, 62, 62, lastRow, lastRow);  (Translate Results to 1/0 format)
  var cell = Data.getRange( lastRow, 62, 1, 1);
  var S2RadSurveyPass = Source.getRange(23, 3);
  var cell = Data.getRange(lastRow, 62, 1, 1);
  if( S2RadSurveyPass.getValue() == "Pass") {
    cell.setValue(1);
    }
  else  {
    cell.setValue(0);
    };

// not needed  var S2LeakagePass = Source.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 63, 63, lastRow, lastRow);  //No field
// not needed  var S2MaxCountsPass = Source.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 64, 64, lastRow, lastRow);  //No field

  var EnergyCorrectedDose = Source.getRange(19, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 65, 65, lastRow, lastRow); 
  var VolumeCorrectionFactor = Source.getRange(19, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 66, 66, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var CountCorrectionFactor = Source.getRange(9,6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 67, 67, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var SourceLeakCalEnergyCorrected = Source.getRange(21, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 68, 68, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var SourceLeakSourceIntensityCorrected = Source.getRange(21, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 69, 69, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var HourlyCalLeakage = Source.getRange(22, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 70, 70, lastRow, lastRow);  

  var BackgroundCorrectedLeakage1 = WDevice.getRange(11, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 71, 71, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var BackgroundCorrectedLeakage2 = WDevice.getRange(12, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 72, 72, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var BackgroundCorrectedLeakage3 = WDevice.getRange(13, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 73, 73, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var BackgroundCorrectedLeakage4 = WDevice.getRange(14, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 74, 74, lastRow, lastRow); 
  var BackgroundCorrectedLeakage5 = WDevice.getRange(15, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 75, 75, lastRow, lastRow);  

// not needed  var BackgroundCorrectedLeakageMean = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 76, 76, lastRow, lastRow);   //No field
// not needed   var BackgroundCorrectedLeakageMax = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 77, 77, lastRow, lastRow);   //No field

  var EnergyCorrectedLeakage1 = WDevice.getRange(11, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 78, 78, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var EnergyCorrectedLeakage2 = WDevice.getRange(12, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 79, 79, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var EnergyCorrectedLeakage3 = WDevice.getRange(13, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 80, 80, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var EnergyCorrectedLeakage4 = WDevice.getRange(14, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 81, 81, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var EnergyCorrectedLeakage5 = WDevice.getRange(15, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 82, 82, lastRow, lastRow);  

// not needed  var EnergyCorrectedLeakageMean = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 83, 83, lastRow, lastRow);   //No field
  var EnergyCorrectedLeakageMax = WDevice.getRange(21, 5).copyValuesToRange(Data, 84, 84, lastRow, lastRow);  

  var SourceIntensityCorrectedLeakage1 = WDevice.getRange(11, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 85, 85, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var SourceIntensityCorrectedLeakage2 = WDevice.getRange(12, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 86, 86, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var SourceIntensityCorrectedLeakage3 = WDevice.getRange(13, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 87, 87, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var SourceIntensityCorrectedLeakage4 = WDevice.getRange(14, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 88, 88, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var SourceIntensityCorrectedLeakage5 = WDevice.getRange(15, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 89, 89, lastRow, lastRow);  

// not needed  var SourceIntensityLeakageMean = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 90, 90, lastRow, lastRow);   //No field
  var SourceIntensityLeakageMax = WDevice.getRange(21, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 91, 91, lastRow, lastRow);  

  var CountCorrectedLeakage1 = Source.getRange(13, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 92, 92, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var CountCorrectedLeakage1 = Source.getRange(14, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 93, 93, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var CountCorrectedLeakage1 = Source.getRange(15, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 94, 94, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var CountCorrectedLeakage1 = Source.getRange(16, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 95, 95, lastRow, lastRow);  
  var CountCorrectedLeakage1 = Source.getRange(17, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 96, 96, lastRow, lastRow);  

// not needed  var CountCorrectedLeakageMean = WDevice.getRange(6, 6).copyValuesToRange(Data, 97, 97, lastRow, lastRow);   //No field
  var CountCorrectedLeakageMax = Source.getRange(23, 7).copyValuesToRange(Data, 98, 98, lastRow, lastRow);   

 // Store Paramters

  var maxSourceIntensity = Parameters.getRange(3, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 101, 101, lastRow, lastRow);
  var maxSourceIntensityFiltered = Parameters.getRange(4, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 102, 102, lastRow, lastRow);
  var minSourceIntensity = Parameters.getRange(5, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 103, 103, lastRow, lastRow);
  var maxSourceCounts = Parameters.getRange(6, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 104, 104, lastRow, lastRow);
  var minSourceCounts = Parameters.getRange(7, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 105, 105, lastRow, lastRow);
  var sourceIntensificationFactor = Parameters.getRange(8, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 106, 106, lastRow, lastRow);
  var largePressureEnergyCorrection = Parameters.getRange(9, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 107, 107, lastRow, lastRow);
  var smallPressureEnergyCorrection = Parameters.getRange(10, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 108, 108, lastRow, lastRow);
  var waterChamberEnergyCorrection = Parameters.getRange(11, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 109, 109, lastRow, lastRow);
  var leakageLimit = Parameters.getRange(12, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 110, 110, lastRow, lastRow);
  var calcMaxSorceIntLeakageLimit = Parameters.getRange(13, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 111, 111, lastRow, lastRow);
  var calPerHour = Parameters.getRange(14, 4).copyValuesToRange(Data, 112, 112, lastRow, lastRow);

// Finish Test Script Function
  Vapor.getRange(4, 7).setValue(""); //clear testerID 
  Vapor.getRange(7,10).setValue("Survey Recorded");
  Logger.log(Vapor.getRange(4, 7).getValue()); //Force Sheet Display Update
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  Vapor.getRange(7,10).setValue("");

 };
```

Comment: I am sorry about your issue, however, your question is open ended and vague. Also, we can only speculate what is wrong without much information. If you can at least the paste code you are trying to run, when you get that error it would be helpful.

Comment: Do I add it in here as a comment, or click Answer Your Question and make another big reply?

Comment: You should be able to edit your question, you can add to it. Use the code tag `{}`

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Comment: On [mcve] there are guidelines about posting questions about code that isn't working.

Comment: Well, the code probably works fine. It hasn't changed at all since last week, when it worked. All scripts on our Google Docs account do not function. When they are executed by an image button it says "Script function xxx could not found".

Answer (score -1):

I am curious if this had anything to do with the phishing attempt that happened last week. Perhaps your domain has blocked scripts or something- I would contact them- Also I would check here to see if its connected.
 https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1